# Unable to mock a service and return data in angular unit test - says undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following component for which I am trying to write a unit tests for. When I run the below test, I see value for

```
console.log('**fav**' + favorite[`isFavorite`]);
```

as `undefined` meaning the data that I am trying to return by mocking service is not getting returned I think. My understanding is that in order to test it, I should mock the service and return data, which then would call `handleData` and executes. Where is the mistake I am committing?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.favoriteService.getData().subscribe(item => {
      if (Object.keys(item).length) {
        this.handleData(item);
      }
    });
  }

  handleData(favorite) {
    console.log('**fav**' + favorite[`isFavorite`]);
    if (favorite[`isFavorite`]) {
      console.log('****1****');
      // some logic
    } else {
      // some logic
    }
  }
```

Following is my spec file -

```
describe('FavoritesComponent', () => {
  let component: FavoritesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FavoritesComponent>;
  let stubFavoriteGatewaySpec: StubFavoriteGatewaySpec;
  let spyFavoriteService: jasmine.SpyObj<FavoriteService>;

  const favouriteData = [
    {
      tickerTypeName: 'Market Price',
      type: 'MP',
      headers: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
      data: [
        [1, '1.020'],
        [0, '-0.250'],
        [-5, '-4.560'],
        [-149, '-149.000'],
      ],
      isFavorite: true,
    }
  ];

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    stubFavoriteGatewaySpec = new StubFavoriteGatewaySpec();
    spyFavoriteService = jasmine.createSpyObj('FavoriteService', [
      'getData',
    ]);
    spyFavoriteService.getData.and.returnValues(of(favouriteData));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatExpansionModule],
      declarations: [FavoritesComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: FavoritesGateway, useValue: stubFavoriteGatewaySpec },
        { provide: FavoriteService, useValue: spyFavoriteService },
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .catch(console.log);
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FavoritesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Some people just mark a question negative without caring to leave a comment behind - the reason.

Comment: Are you getting values for console.log(favorite) ? or it's undefined

Comment: @uiTeam324 it says `'**fav**[object Object]'`. Is it because I am returning an array and it expects an object?

Comment: try to log it using `JSON.stringify();`. See if you have the same data or not whatever you are passing it through `spy`

Comment: @uiTeam324 it's the same data in an array like defined in the spec.

Comment: @uiTeam324 mate, you hit the nail right. How can I send an object and not an array in here `spyFavoriteService.getData.and.returnValues(of(favouriteData))`, any idea please? You can post that as an answer too.

Comment: Ok got it. The problem is your are passing an Array and isFavorite is in index 0, Either pass an `object` through the spy or handle it like this `console.log('**fav**' + favorite[0].isFavorite);`

Comment: @uiTeam324 yes, you are exactly right. How can I pass an object, I didn't get any reference on that one. Moreover, the service expects an observable to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Mock

```
const favouriteData = {
  tickerTypeName: 'Market Price',
  type: 'MP',
  headers: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
  data: [
    [1, '1.020'],
    [0, '-0.250'],
    [-5, '-4.560'],
    [-149, '-149.000'],
  ],
  isFavorite: true,
};
```

//test

```
it(
'should set the favorite to true onload',
fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(spyFavoriteService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(favouriteData));
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.isFavorite).toBeTruthy();
 //test your other logic 
})
);
```

No need to spy on `beforeEach`, Mock it on test level. Not sure what you are trying to do inside handle function, if you have a component variable like `isFavorite` then it should work.

if using Angular 12 use `waitForAync` instead of `fakeAsync`.

Comment: The problem is it gives me an error at `spyOn(spyFavoriteService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of(favouriteData));` - `is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any[]>`, that's something I am unable to figure out. It expects an array of Observable

Comment: `Mock it on test level.`  - its doesn't work and returns undefined in the subscribe block.